# Set built-in logging of celery task to DEBUG, while keeping my own messages at a higher level

Tags: celery

I'm using celery 5 and would like to suppress the built-in celery worker log messages like

> Task xxx.tasks.module.function[ab91bbaf-6da0-4860-94d1-a8886892336a] succeeded in 0.12619075924158096s: None

At the same time, messages that I explicitly want to log using my own `logger.info()` statements should remain visible. Could I set the built-in ones, as well as those belonging to celery.app.trace etc, to log at the DEBUG level and the rest at the INFO level to avoid having too much log pollution?